# How do I load a contact Photo?

Tags: android, contactscontract

I'm having trouble loading a photo for a contact in Android. I've googled for an answer, but so far have come up empty. Does anyone have an example of querying for a Contact, then loading the Photo?

So, given a contactUri which comes from an Activity result called using

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI),PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST)
```

is:

> content://com.android.contacts/data/1557

The loadContact(..) works fine. However when I call the getPhoto(...) method, I get a null value for the photo InputStream. It is also confusing because the URI values are different. The contactPhotoUri evaluates to:

> content://com.android.contacts/contacts/1557

See the comments inline in the code below.

```
 class ContactAccessor {

    /**
     * Retrieves the contact information.
     */
    public ContactInfo loadContact(ContentResolver contentResolver, Uri contactUri) {

        //contactUri --> content://com.android.contacts/data/1557

        ContactInfo contactInfo = new ContactInfo();

        // Load the display name for the specified person
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(contactUri,
                                            new String[]{Contacts._ID, 
                                                         Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, 
                                                         Phone.NUMBER,
                                                         Contacts.PHOTO_ID}, null, null, null);
        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                contactInfo.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
                contactInfo.setDisplayName(cursor.getString(1));
                contactInfo.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }        
        return contactInfo;  // <-- returns info for contact
    }

    public Bitmap getPhoto(ContentResolver contentResolver, Long contactId) {
        Uri contactPhotoUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);

        // contactPhotoUri --> content://com.android.contacts/contacts/1557

        InputStream photoDataStream = Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(contentResolver,contactPhotoUri); // <-- always null
        Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(photoDataStream);
        return photo;
    }

    public class ContactInfo {

        private long id;
        private String displayName;
        private String phoneNumber;
        private Uri photoUri;

        public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
            this.displayName = displayName;
        }

        public String getDisplayName() {
            return displayName;
        }

        public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        }

        public String getPhoneNumber() {
            return phoneNumber;
        }

        public Uri getPhotoUri() {
            return this.photoUri;
        }

        public void setPhotoUri(Uri photoUri) {
            this.photoUri = photoUri;
        }

        public long getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

    }
}
```

Clearly, I'm doing something wrong here, but I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. Thanks.

Comment: So is there no decent solution? If the contacts use facebook photos, we're SOL?

Comment: I wasn't able to find a way to load photos from facebook. I don't know if it changed in Froyo or not.

Comment: whey are you not using Contacts.PHOTO_ID after reading from cursor ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Having scanned the many questions and answers to the problem of displaying a thumbnail I thought I would post my solution to this particular conundrum as I could only find a couple that worked at all and none that provided a good canned solution for the lazy developer.

The class below takes a Context, QuickContactBadge and a telephone number and will attach a locally stored image to the badge if there is one available for the specified phone number.

Here's the class:

```
public final class QuickContactHelper {

private static final String[] PHOTO_ID_PROJECTION = new String[] {
    ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID
};

private static final String[] PHOTO_BITMAP_PROJECTION = new String[] {
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO
};

private final QuickContactBadge badge;

private final String phoneNumber;

private final ContentResolver contentResolver;

public QuickContactHelper(final Context context, final QuickContactBadge badge, final String phoneNumber) {

    this.badge = badge;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

}

public void addThumbnail() {

    final Integer thumbnailId = fetchThumbnailId();
    if (thumbnailId != null) {
        final Bitmap thumbnail = fetchThumbnail(thumbnailId);
        if (thumbnail != null) {
            badge.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        }
    }

}

private Integer fetchThumbnailId() {

    final Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    final Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, PHOTO_ID_PROJECTION, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

    try {
        Integer thumbnailId = null;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            thumbnailId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID));
        }
        return thumbnailId;
    }
    finally {
        cursor.close();
    }

}

final Bitmap fetchThumbnail(final int thumbnailId) {

    final Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, thumbnailId);
    final Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, PHOTO_BITMAP_PROJECTION, null, null, null);

    try {
        Bitmap thumbnail = null;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final byte[] thumbnailBytes = cursor.getBlob(0);
            if (thumbnailBytes != null) {
                thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(thumbnailBytes, 0, thumbnailBytes.length);
            }
        }
        return thumbnail;
    }
    finally {
        cursor.close();
    }

}

}
```

And here's a typical use case inside an activity:

```
String phoneNumber = "...";
QuickContactBadge badge = (QuickContactBadge) view.findViewById(R.id.friend);
new QuickContactHelper(this, badge, phoneNumber).addThumbnail();
```

In a fragment it will be slightly different:

```
String phoneNumber = "...";
QuickContactBadge badge = (QuickContactBadge) view.findViewById(R.id.friend);
new QuickContactHelper(getActivity(), badge, phoneNumber).addThumbnail();
```

Now there are ways to be more efficient - for example if you are rendering a message timeline you'd want to re-use the same bitmap object for every badge instance for a given phone number instead of constantly creating new helper class instances and re-retrieving the bitmap - but my purpose here was to post a solution that is stripped down to the absolute minimum for clarity whilst at the same time providing a complete and usable solution out of the box. This solution has been built and tested on Andriod 4.0, and tested on 4.1 as well.

Answer (score 34):

This works for me:

```
public static Bitmap loadContactPhoto(ContentResolver cr, long  id) {
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
    InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);
    if (input == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
}
```

Comment: People keep saying alternative methods work. But I have not seen one work on a stock device (I think HTC's sync adapter works differently). Can anyone confirm that a user with both a Google contact and Facebook contact (but only the facebook contact has a photo) can get the photo to appear on a phone that only has the Facebook app sync adapter?

Comment: Hey ..  Here in function you passed id .. Is it Photo id or Contact Id ?

Comment: This method should call `input.close()` before returning.

Comment: Worked great! Awesome.

Comment: This answer is still valid, but it fetches the thumbnail of the photo, which is a low quality.
Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23120749/7883681

Answer (score 17):

After a lot of debugging nights I discover that the best approach is to use the `contact id` and if it fails to use the `photo id`.

```
public static Bitmap loadContactPhoto(ContentResolver cr, long  id,long photo_id) 
{

    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
    InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);
    if (input != null) 
    {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("PHOTO","first try failed to load photo");

    }

    byte[] photoBytes = null;

    Uri photoUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, photo_id);

    Cursor c = cr.query(photoUri, new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO}, null, null, null);

    try 
    {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) 
            photoBytes = c.getBlob(0);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        c.close();
    }           

    if (photoBytes != null)
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photoBytes,0,photoBytes.length);
    else
        Log.d("PHOTO","second try also failed");
    return null;
}
```

the code tested on emulator and Nexus S device and seems to work.

Comment: This is the only piece of code I have found to be actually working with all kind of photos. +1

update: unfortunatelly it doesn't work on Samsung Galaxy S2 running latest Gingerbread Stock rom. :/

Comment: Running off of ICS and JellyBean, this is the only routine I've managed to run. Will check out how it works in Gingerbread, though, and see if there is a way to make it work everywhere.

Answer (score 16):

Guys, I spent many hours attempting to figure this out. Here is a method I created that will get you your facebook photo by phone number (no dashes). You can, of course, modify it accordingly:

```
    public Bitmap getFacebookPhoto(String phoneNumber) {
    Uri phoneUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Uri photoUri = null;
    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
    Cursor contact = cr.query(phoneUri,
            new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID }, null, null, null);

    if (contact.moveToFirst()) {
        long userId = contact.getLong(contact.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        photoUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, userId);

    }
    else {
        Bitmap defaultPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
        return defaultPhoto;
    }
    if (photoUri != null) {
        InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(
                cr, photoUri);
        if (input != null) {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        }
    } else {
        Bitmap defaultPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
        return defaultPhoto;
    }
    Bitmap defaultPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
    return defaultPhoto;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it doesn't work on my HTC Sensation (Sense 3.0). IMHO, I think your code also do nothing more than get the contactId and then feed it to openContactPhotoInputStream - it doesn't differ from code from @wrongmissle.In fact, the result of 2 solutions are the same on my phone

Comment: This works on my HTC Desire HD. However, if I have a contacts array of more than 261 contacts, it force closes. I am looping throw an array: photoarray[a] = getFacebookPhoto(storage[a][0]); where the [a][0] is the phone number. So if storage.length>261, it force closes. Any ideas? The array is declared as photoarray = new Bitmap[storage.length];

Comment: @erdomester It could be because it takes to much time, and you app seems to be blocking the CPU. You should do this in a background thread, which would not block the main/UI thread!

Comment: Thank you so much. Great job. This work in my HTC Sensation (or pyramid lol).

Answer (score 5):

None of these approaches worked for me. What did work was:

```
String[] projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID,                 ///< the correct ID for photo retrieval in loadLocalContactPhotoBytes()
//              ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
//              ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO
        };

        ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver();

        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                //      Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                //              new String[] {RawContacts._ID, RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME},
                //              new String[] {Contacts._ID},
                projection, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

....
```

//the 'cursor' above got passed as an argument below

```
    private byte[] loadLocalContactPhotoBytes(ContentResolver cr, Cursor cursor, byte[] defaultPhotoBytes)
    {
        byte[] photoBytes = null;// = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO));

//      int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID));
//      Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
//      Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        Uri photoUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, id);

        Cursor c = cr.query(photoUri, new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO}, null, null, null);

        try 
        {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) 
                photoBytes = c.getBlob(0);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.w(_TAG, e.toString());

        } finally {

            c.close();
        }           

        photoBytes = photoBytes == null ? defaultPhotoBytes : photoBytes;
        return photoBytes;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for kicks I copied most of the answers here into a single class to see if any of them would succeed in getting the Facebook thumbnail. They didn't.... But, here is what I did to perhaps save you doing the same.

It shows the results in a dialog for ease.

Please be aware - **it's not optimised and you'll need to catch errors and close cursors etc**:

To start the contact picker intent:

```
private static final int SELECT_CONTACT = 1468;

Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
contactPickerIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

try {
    startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, SELECT_CONTACT);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The callback:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (data != null && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        switch (requestCode) {

        case SELECT_CONTACT:

            Uri contactURI = data.getData();

            if (contactURI != null) {

                String contactID = data.getData().getLastPathSegment().trim();

                String contactName = ContactThumb.getDisplayName(getActivity(), contactURI);

                if (contactName != null && !contactName.isEmpty() && contactID != null && !contactID.isEmpty()) {

                    final int THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 100;

                    Bitmap contactThumb = ContactThumb.loadContactPhoto(getActivity(), Long.valueOf(contactID));

                    if (contactThumb != null) {

                        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                        final int width = contactThumb.getWidth();
                        final int height = contactThumb.getHeight();
                        final int ratio = width / height;

                        final Bitmap resized = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(contactThumb, (THUMBNAIL_SIZE * ratio),
                                THUMBNAIL_SIZE);

                        Drawable icon = new BitmapDrawable(getActivity().getResources(), resized);

                        alert.setIcon(icon);

                        alert.setTitle("Contact details");

                        final TextView homeTV = new TextView(getActivity());

                        homeTV.setText(contactName + " : " + contactID);
                        homeTV.setTextSize(12);

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                            homeTV.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        }

                        homeTV.setPadding(30, 2, 20, 10);
                        homeTV.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

                        alert.setView(homeTV);
                        alert.show();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Photo null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            }

            break;
        }
    } else {
        // cancelled or error
    }
}
```

The ContactThumb attempts....

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
import android.util.Log;

public class ContactThumb {

private static final String TAG = "THUMB";

public static String getDisplayName(final Context ctx, final Uri contactURI) {

    String cname = null;

    try {

        final String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
        final Cursor cursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(contactURI, projection, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {

            try {

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    cname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                }

            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }

        }

    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return cname;
}

public static Bitmap loadContactPhoto(final Context ctx, final long contactId) {

    final Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);

    final InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(ctx.getContentResolver(), contactUri);

    if (input != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "loadContactPhoto: input");

        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

    } else {

        byte[] photoBytes = null;

        Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);

        final Cursor c = ctx.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
                new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO }, null, null, null);

        try {

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                photoBytes = c.getBlob(0);
            }

        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            c.close();
        }

        if (photoBytes != null) {

            Log.i(TAG, "loadContactPhoto: photoBytes");

            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photoBytes, 0, photoBytes.length);

        } else {

            Bitmap another = finalAttempt(ctx, contactId);

            if (another != null) {

                Log.i(TAG, "loadContactPhoto: another");

                return another;
            } else {

                Log.i(TAG, "loadContactPhoto: might be returning default");

                return getFacebookPhoto(ctx, getContactNumber(ctx, String.valueOf(contactId)));
            }
        }
    }
}

public static String getContactNumber(final Context ctx, final String contactID) {

    Cursor phones = null;

    try {

        phones = ctx.getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactID, null, null);

        String cnum = null;

        if (phones != null && phones.getCount() > 0) {

            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                cnum = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));

                if (cnum != null && !cnum.isEmpty() && !cnum.contains("@")) {

                    Log.i(TAG, "getContactNumbers: : cnum: " + cnum);

                    try {
                        phones.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return cnum;
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

public static Bitmap getFacebookPhoto(final Context ctx, String phoneNumber) {

    Uri phoneUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Uri photoUri = null;
    ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver();

    Cursor contact = cr.query(phoneUri, new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID }, null, null, null);

    if (contact.moveToFirst()) {
        long userId = contact.getLong(contact.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        photoUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, userId);

    } else {
        Bitmap defaultPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
        return defaultPhoto;
    }
    if (photoUri != null) {
        InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, photoUri);
        if (input != null) {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        }
    } else {
        Bitmap defaultPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
        return defaultPhoto;
    }
    Bitmap defaultPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
    return defaultPhoto;
}

public static Bitmap finalAttempt(final Context ctx, final long contactId) {

    byte[] photoBytes = null;

    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, };

    ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver();

    final Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, contactId);

    Cursor cursor = cr.query(contactUri, projection, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID));
        Uri photoUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, id);

        Cursor c = cr.query(photoUri, new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO }, null, null, null);

        try {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                photoBytes = c.getBlob(0);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {
            cursor.close();
            c.close();
        }

        if (photoBytes != null) {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photoBytes, 0, photoBytes.length);
        }
    }

    return null;
}

}
```

If any of the methods work for you, please upvote the answer I've copied and pasted the code from!

Check this link for the [Android Developers suggested way](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.html)

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

It seems that my problem was because the contacts in my device were synced from facebook, and the photo therefore is not available.

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/be8d0cf3928e4b7f

Comment: and why the default contact application shows the facebook photo?

Comment: because facebook grants the right to access the contact photo to the contact app but not to other unknown apps.

Comment: I am also developing an sms app, and still have problem with loading facebook contact photos. I think there's a solution for sure, because Handcent SMS can display all those photos. @PaulH: Have you found any solution yet ?

Answer (score 2):

Android documentation says, that we should do it in this way.

```
public Bitmap openPhoto(long contactId) {
        Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
        Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
                new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.PHOTO}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);
                if (data != null) {
                    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
                }
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return null;

}
```

contactId stands for:

```
getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID))
```

source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.html

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found the solution at: [Displaying the Quick Contact Badge](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/display-contact-badge.html)

My code with some minor modifications, works fine for me

```
    public Bitmap loadContactPhoto(String name) {
    String photoUri = null;     
    int thumbnailColumn;        
    ContentResolver cr = GlobalData.instance().getContext().getContentResolver();
    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID ,ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID,  ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI, ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI};
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + "='" + name + "'", null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) 
                thumbnailColumn =   cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI);
            else
                thumbnailColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup._ID);

            photoUri = cursor.getString(thumbnailColumn);

            if(photoUri != null)
                return loadContactPhotoThumbnail(photoUri);
            else
                return null;    
    }
    return null;
}
private Bitmap loadContactPhotoThumbnail(String photoData) {
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
    try {

        Uri thumbUri;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            thumbUri = Uri.parse(photoData);
        } else {
            final Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, photoData);
            thumbUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        }
        afd = GlobalData.instance().getContext().getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(thumbUri, "r");
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = afd.getFileDescriptor();
        if (fileDescriptor != null)
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor, null, null);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } finally {
        if (afd != null) {
            try {
                afd.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /contacts/27/photo