# Exception when getting photo content of contacts..

Tags: android

I am using below code to  get the photo from my contacts..
but this is throwing exception..

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error: INTEGER data in getBlob_native.
```

please help  me if I miss something.

```
int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID);

byte[] img = cursor.getBlob(idx);


ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView); 

Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length);
```

Answer (score 6):

The error is happing because you are trying to read the PHOTO_ID column as a blob. PHOTO_ID is a integer column that is the id of the row in the ContactsContract.Data provider that you can read to get the photo data.

Comment: Thank you sooo much for this piece of information, this was driving me nuts... The documentation for PHOTO_ID says "Reference to the row in the data table holding the photo." I guess when they say "the data table" they mean the ContactsContract.Data table.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Nic's answer this recent question may help you:

[Android - How do I load a contact Photo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383580/android-how-do-i-load-a-contact-photo)