# Load a contact's picture into a listview instead of the default?

Tags: android, contacts, image, contactscontract

I created a listview containing my contacts...

***tab_contact_list.xml***, contains the listview:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/tab_contact_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

***listview_detail_tab_contact_list.xml***, details rows of listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/defaultavatar" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contact_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Who am I"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contact_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="000000000" />

    </LinearLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
```

***defaultavatar.png*** is in folder *drawable* [image: defaultavatar.png]

And, I have some classes:

```
public class ContactStock {

    private String name;
    private String number;

    public ContactStock(String name, String number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }

}
```

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private final Activity activity;
    private final List stocks;

    public ContactListAdapter(Activity activity, List objects) {
        super(activity, R.layout.listview_detail_tab_contact_list, objects);
        this.activity = activity;
        this.stocks = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = convertView;
        ContactStockView sv = null;
        if (rowView == null) {
            // Get a new instance of the row layout view
            LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.listview_detail_tab_contact_list, null);

            // Hold the view objects in an object,
            // so they don't need to be re-fetched
            sv = new ContactStockView();
            sv.name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);

            sv.number = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.contact_number);

            // Cache the view objects in the tag,
            // so they can be re-accessed later
            rowView.setTag(sv);
        } else {
            sv = (ContactStockView) rowView.getTag();
        }
        // Transfer the stock data from the data object
        // to the view objects
        ContactStock currentStock = (ContactStock) stocks.get(position);
        sv.name.setText(currentStock.getName());
        sv.number.setText(currentStock.getNumber());

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return rowView;
    }

    protected static class ContactStockView {
        protected TextView name;
        protected TextView number;
    }
}
```

I have class display the listview:

```
public class addlistfromcontact extends Activity {
    private ListView lst;
    private List<ContactStock> contactstock;
    private Cursor mCursor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_contact_list);
        lst = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tab_contact_list);
        contactstock = new ArrayList<ContactStock>();

        mCursor = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'", null,
                ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        int number = mCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);      
        int name = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME);
        while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String phName = mCursor.getString(name);
            String phNumber = mCursor.getString(number);
            contactstock.add(new ContactStock(phName, phNumber));
        }
        lst.setAdapter(new ContactListAdapter(addlistfromcontact.this,
                contactstock));
    }

}
```

And my result looks like this:

[image: Listview results]

Now how do I display each contact's picture instead of defaultavatar.png?

Comment: please provide answer for your question Thuong I also stucked with the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have a mistake.  The

```
long phId=mCursor.getLong(id);
```

should be part of the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try using your Model to hold the picture..

```
public class ContactStock {

    private Bitmap picture;

    // your current code goes here       

    public void setPicture(Bitmap picture) {
        this.picture = picture;
    }

    public Bitmap getPicture() {
        return picture;
    }
}
```

make sure you implement the getPicture() method in your ArrayAdapter, you only use your name and number object there, in your xml for your row you have the imageview there already, just add it to the ArrayAdapter ... so how do you get the bitmap?? this worked for me...

```
public Bitmap loadContactPhoto(ContentResolver cr, long id) { 
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id); 
    InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri); 
    if (input == null) { 
return null; 
    } 
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input); 
}
```

StackOverflow member "wrongmissle" posted this here. [How do I load a contact Photo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383580/android-how-do-i-load-a-contact-photo)
thanks wrongmissle.
Since you can already get the name and number of a contact just pull the id, plug it into that method with a ContentResolver, that returns a bitmap that can be placed on your list! hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer might give you error... Here is a 100% working code

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                             Bitmap bitmap = null;
                            try {
                                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contexts.getContentResolver(), uri);
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                bitmap = null;
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                bitmap = null;
                            }


                            if(bitmap != null)
                                friend.setImageURI(uri);
                            else
                                friend.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar_photo);
```

Where ImageView is friend.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to add a bitmap to the `ContactStock` class,
this will save the contact photo.
change the end of the adapter class to the following code:

```
        ContactStock currentStock = (ContactStock) stocks.get(position);
        sv.name.setText(currentStock.getName());
        sv.number.setText(currentStock.getNumber());
        sv.image.setImageBitmap(currentStock.getPicture());


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return rowView;
    }

    protected static class ContactStockView {
        protected TextView name;
        protected TextView number;
        protected ImageView image;
    }
```

to the main activity (`AddlistFromContact`) add the following function:

```
public Bitmap getPhoto(long userId ) {
        Uri photoUri = null;
        ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
        photoUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, userId);
        Bitmap defaultPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.contacts);
        if (photoUri != null) {
            InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(
                    cr, photoUri);
            if (input != null) {
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            }
        } else {

            return defaultPhoto;
        }

        return defaultPhoto;
    }
```

now all you need to do is add to your `onCreate()` function this two lines, after you have defined the cursor of course:

```
    int id=mCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.CONTACT_ID);
    long phId=mCursor.getLong(id);
```

and call the constractur of contactStock in the following way:

```
contactstock.add(new ContactStock(phName, phNumber,getPhoto(phId)));
```

hope I've helped