# File not found exception in setImageURI();

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-file

i am setting contact image which is in the sd card,and through my application i am trying to diplay it in a list adapter.I am able to get the image uri properly. but when i am trying to set the

```
img.setImageURI(uri);
```

some times i am getting file not found exception.Even problem with converting the uri into bitmap.I have four contacts in that 2 contact with image is displaying properly,remaining two i am getting file not found exception.please help.

Comment: try using img.setImageURI(Uri.Parse("sdcard_image_path"));

Answer (score 0):

See this link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4240238/1441666

```
public static Bitmap loadContactPhoto(ContentResolver cr, long  id) {
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
    InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);
    if (input == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
}
```

Comment: hey. i am getting the contact image uri like "content: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/7/photo". Its telling this file not found exception