# How to get merged Contact's photo?

Tags: android, facebook, contacts

I am trying to figure out how to get the photo for a merged contact, to display in a QuickContactBadge. I've been searching and googling, and all the things I can find online say this is not possible if the contact's default image comes from a Facebook sync. However all the examples I find also reference Froyo or Gingerbread.

Is there still no way to do this in the ICS/JB age?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383580/how-do-i-load-a-contact-photo) seemed the most promising, but the comments seem to say it is hit or miss. 
None of the things I've found online have worked for me.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
public static Uri getContactPhotoUri(long ContactId) {
    Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, ContactId);
    Uri photo = Uri.withAppendedPath(person, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);

    Cursor cur = App.ContentResolver().query(
        Data.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] { Data._ID },
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
            + "="
            + ContactId
            + " AND "
            + Data.MIMETYPE
            + "='"
            + Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
            + "'", null, Data.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC");
    Uri rv = null;
    rv = (cur == null || !cur.moveToFirst())? null: photo; 
    if (cur != null) cur.close();

    return rv;
}
```

It shows the image properly for contacts where the image comes from the google contact.
The image does ***not*** show properly for contacts where the primary image comes from Facebook.

Is there *REALLY*, still, no reliable way to get the default image for a contact regardless of where the image comes from?

**EDIT** (01/18/2013): I've also tried querying the PHOTO_URI and PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI as follows, with the same results.

```
public static String[] GroupMembersProjection = new String[] {
    Contacts._ID,
    Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY, 
    Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
    Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI
};

public static Cursor getGroupMembers(int groupid, String sort) {
    String ord; 
    if (sort.equals("A")) { ord = Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY; } 
    else { ord = Contacts.TIMES_CONTACTED + " DESC"; /* SORT = "U"; DEFAULT */ }

    ContentResolver cr = App.ContentResolver();
    Cursor contacts = cr.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, 
                GroupMembersProjection, 
                GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID + "=" + groupid, null, ord);
    return contacts;
}
```

Additionally, I tried querying `PHOTO_ID` instead of the PHOTO_URI fields, and then using the following code to get the URI manually and use that for the image, but this also yields the same results, showing google images, but not Facebook ones.

```
Uri puri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, photoid);
```