# Android doesn't deliver correct PHOTO_URI

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I am using a `QuickContactBadge`. Now I get this messages on a Sony Xperia P. I developed the app on CyanogenMod and eveything was fine.

```
Unable to open content: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/939/photo
java.io.FileNotFoundException: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/939/photo
```

This is my code:

```
projection = new String[] {
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI };

contactCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        projection, null, null, null);


...

thumbnail = contactCursor.getString(contactCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));

...

quickContactBadge.setImageURI(Uri.parse(ThumbnailString));
```

My suggestion was that the Sony ROM doesn't deliver an valid PHOTO_URI but it looks legit.

Answer (score -1):

The Solution is quit simple.

I discovered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383580/how-do-i-load-a-contact-photo) Question which solves the Problem.