# Picasso loads PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI but not PHOTO_URI

Tags: java, android, android-contacts, picasso

Loading images with Picasso is seemingly so easy, until I hit this roadblock. Not sure why! I can load photos from contacts via PHOTO_URI if the contacts only have a thumbnail, or, if I instead ask for PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI specifically.

```
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        ImageView icon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ContactImage);
        String photoUri = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI));

        if (photoUri == null) {
            icon.setImageDrawable(null);
        } else {
            Picasso.with(context).load(photoUri).into(icon);
        }
    }
```

For what it's worth: if I use `Picasso.with(context).load(photoUri).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).error(R.drawable.error).into(icon);` then I see the placeholder image in the place of every contact who has a high res image. I never see an "error" picture. If I revert back to just using `icon.setImageURI(Uri.parse(photoUri));` then I see the high res contact images again just fine. (But then I don't have a snazzy async caching picture loader!)

UPDATE: Thanks to @copolii and his answers below, the following now works flawlessly with Picasso 2.1.1:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    Long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
    Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
    String photoUri = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI));

    ImageView icon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ContactImage);

    if (photoUri == null) {
        icon.setImageDrawable(null);
    } else {
        Picasso
            .with(context)
            .load(contactUri)
            .into(icon);
    }

}
```

This loads the higher-res photo, if there is one, and if not, shows the low-res photo, and if there is no photo set for a contact, it's set to a blank / null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using a `contact uri`?

That last boolean parameter in `openContactPhotoInputStream` promises to get you the high res photo if one is available.

Instead of using a `photo uri` use a `contact uri` or a `contact lookup uri`.

**UPDATE**
Since the question has been answered, I though I'd post the relevant details here:
A small test app is posted here (You need Android Studio): https://github.com/copolii/PicassoContactsTest

If you set both a `placeholder` and an `error` icon, the `error` icon is displayed for contacts who do not have a picture. I'd recommend setting the *social face guy* as your place-holder and no error icon. That way, your place-holder stays on if the contact has no picture.

If you **do** want to differentiate between the two, choose your error icon with the above in mind (i.e. don't use a *big red OMFG* error indicator).

**--- Previous Content ---**

Let me know if that helps.

I did the work for the contacts photo loading and unless I'm missing something, you should get the high resolution picture (API 14+) automatically:

```
if (SDK_INT < ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
  return openContactPhotoInputStream(contentResolver, uri);
} else {
  return openContactPhotoInputStream(contentResolver, uri, true);
}
```

It seems that the openContactPhotoInputStream doesn't like the PHOTO_URI.

[Android Docs: openContactPhotoInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#openContactPhotoInputStream%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri,%20boolean%29)

If the URIs are distinguishable I can easily add support for PHOTO_URI as well (I have to find out how to load it first though). I'm already determining if the given uri is a *contact photo uri* or a *contact lookup uri* (older android versions do not like lookup uris being fed into `openContactPhotoInputStream` so I have to dereference the *lookup uri* into a *contact uri* before passing it to `openContactPhotoInputStream`).

I hope this helps.

Comment: When I use PHOTO_URI, but a contact doesn't have a high res photo, it returns URIs like `content://com.android.contacts/contacts/38/photo` and it works and displays just fine. But if they have a high res photo, it returns a URI formed like `content://com.android.contacts/display_photo/5`, and this is when I get nothing, or, if set, the placeholder.

Comment: And to be clear, I am only getting a low-res version of their photo if I use PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI, even though I am running KitKat. Definitely above ICS.

Comment: OK, Thanks. that's useful information. It seems like `openContactPhotoInputStream` can't process uris like `content://com.android.contacts/display_photo/5` 
I'll give it a try in an small test app and see what's missing.

Comment: Have you tried using a `contact uri`? That last boolean parameter in `openContactPhotoInputStream` promises to get you the high res photo if one is available.

Instead of using a `photo uri` use a `contact uri` or a `contact lookup uri`.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Can you provide a sample app please so I can verify and fix for 2.2?

Comment: @dnkoutso I'd do this myself and make a pull request, but I'm a bit busy for next little while. To be able to process PHOTO_URI for high res images, you'd have to get is as a BLOB (byte[]) from the Photo table, then feed the byte[] to BitmapFactory.

Found an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13362698/675750

Comment: @copolii - I may need correction on using a "contact URI": I replace the photoUri in the original example with this contactUri `Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);` and I get the error image, if set, or if I use a contact lookup URI, I get the placeholder image, if set. `contactUri` looks like: `content://com.android.contacts/contacts/1491` or `content://com.android.contacts/contacts/255`

Comment: Well, the above was clearly, clearly using the wrong 'id' - silly me. I was using the `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Contacts._ID` instead of `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID`. This now works, with full size images no less! I'll update my above example code with the working code block. Thanks for steering me towards this!

Comment: Any time :)
I put a small test app here: https://github.com/copolii/PicassoContactsTest

I'm gonna make the fix quickly and put in a pull request. It shouldn't be hard. If the `openContactPhotoInputStream` returns null it means the guy doesn't have a picture ... it's not really an error :)

Comment: Having looked at the code, I don't think it's really a bug ... or undesired behaviour. It should probably just be documented (and maybe it is) that if a contact has no display picture (low or high res) it is treated as an error.

Comment: @dnkoutso Pull request submitted.  I've improved the overall handling and detection of the uris as well (no more string comparisons). 
https://github.com/square/picasso/pull/368

Comment: I have also updated the test app (https://github.com/copolii/PicassoContactsTest) to use all 4 uris for testing (wasn't sure how you wanted to handle unit tests).

Comment: lookupuri does not work for thumbnail images on lower android versions (tested on API level 15). Thankyou for mentioning that!