# How do I load Uri photoUri of contact into ImageView Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-cursor

I take photoUri contact by code

```
  Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
  String photoUri = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI));
```

and put it into Image by code

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse(photoUri);
 img.setImageURI(uri);
```

but don't have any image display.

Could any body solve my problem.

Comment: Did you try to print out the content of `photoUri` ? It should be something valid

Comment: Most [image loading libraries](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46) can handle that for you, also handling doing the work on a background thread, so as not to freeze your UI. I recommend Picasso, personally.

Comment: @NguyenQuangAnh result was System.out is "content://com.android.contacts/display_photo/1"

Answer (score 0):

1- Try by creating bitmap from your "photoUri", Add a new function :-

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
try {
    URL url = new URL(src);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    return myBitmap;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}}
```

2- Now set this bitmap to your image view:-

```
 if(photoUri!=null)
   img.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(photoUri));
```

Comment: It seem not true because of function setImageURI() is link URI but function Bitmap isn't it. And I paste your code into my app, it also have problem in function setImageURI().

Comment: @Hoang :- Yes you are right it should be "setImageBitmap()",I have updated my answer please check now !!

Comment: @Hoang :- Also check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23172208/1384010 

Hope this will help you !!!